# program.cpp:12:140: error: in C++98 'x' must be initialized by constructor

Tags: c++

In codeforce he toled me in A. Keyboard 474 equation ... the message is ...

```
Can't compile file: program.cpp: In function 'int main()': program.cpp:12:140: error: in C++98 'x' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}' vector<char> x = { 'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.','/'}; ^ program.cpp:12:140: error: could not convert '{'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/'}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<char>'
```

and this is my code ...

[image: code]

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. What is your platform (compiler, IDE, operating system)?

Comment: This is a very poorly written question that makes it difficult to determine what you're asking, but the problem is clear in the error: if you want to initialise from an `initializer_list`, then you need to use a compiler and command that supports a version of C++ that has `initializer_list`, i.e. C++11. Add `-std=c++11` to the command line, or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: You can't do `vector<char> x = {` in C++98. Try to upgrade your compiler

Answer (score 1):

C++98 supports no `initializer_list` semantics. You have to fall back on arrays which can be initialized with aggregate-lists:

```
char array[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
vector<char> x(array, array + sizeof(array)/sizeof(char));
```

If you do not need a dynamic array anyways, you may just go with the C-array.

Edit: Despite being mentioned countless times already, I also highly suggest to use a modern C++ compiler, if available.

Answer (score 0):

Also as an addendum to Jodocus's answer, I highly recommend that you define a function wherein you can easily call your array via pointers in the referential function's array wherein you are making your logical comparisons.

More so, if you need a library to do this consistently and often in a general form, I reccomend a class structure that you can pull from to define your functions easily.

This will save you time instead of having to copy and paste that array. This is a little harder, but it's worth the time.

Make sure you index your array for functional conditional comparisons or simply at the time of the conditional operation, reference the index value per its returned plaintext value.